# Hiding stack frames without source line in Intellij IDEA

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Programming in Grails there are a lot of useless stack frames in the Intellij IDEA 11 Ultimate debugger. In fact only 3 of 14 visible frames are meaningful, having source line attached, other 11 refers to line -1. (I am talking about frames from my sources only.)

Is it possible to hide those annoying frames?

Comment: Is hiding [frames from libraries](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debug-tool-window-frames.html) good alternative?

Comment: No. That filter is applied already.